# IA32 Assembly - Accessing Arguments

Tags: c, assembly, x86, calling-convention

I am implementing a direct-mapped cache in assembly. I have a C program that defines a function `check_cache()` which I am implementing in a separate IA32 assembly file. The function returns an unsigned char value and accepts 2 arguments: `line cache[4]` and `unsigned char addr`, respectively. The `line cache[4]` argument is a struct representing a cache line. Putting this all together, I have the following C code:

```
typedef struct {
        char valid;
        char tag;
        char block[4];
} line;

unsigned char check_cache(line cache[4], unsigned char addr);
```

My question, then, is how to access the arguments of `check_cache` in my assembly file. Is it based off of the size of the argument? For example, <strike>a C struct is 8 bytes</strike> and a char is 1 byte, so `cache` could be accessed with `movl 8(%ebp), %ecx` and `addr` with `movb 9(%ebp), %cl`. Am I on the right track? Also, is there a way to check if I am getting the correct argument?

My next question is regarding accessing the members of the struct. I was told I could use `shrb` or the `andb` instructions to access `valid`, `tag`, and `block[4]`, but I don't understand why. Can someone explain the idea behind those?

Comment: 1) yes, assuming you set up `ebp` properly. Note that "a C struct is 8 bytes" is nonsense. Even this one is 6 bytes only since all of the fields have alignment 1. Also, your `cache` is going to be a pointer. 2) you check things in a debugger 3) since these are full bytes not bitfields, you don't need to shift and mask.

Comment: "For example, a C struct is 8 bytes": A C struct is whatever size it needs to be to represent the data it holds, which may include some padding.

Comment: @Jester I pushed `ebp` onto the stack and have `esp` stored in it. So, since `cache` is a 4-byte pointer and and `addr` is 1 byte, using `8(%ebp)` and `9(%ebp)` would be the correct way to get them?

Comment: No, `8(%ebp)` is your `cache` but since that takes up 4 bytes, your `addr` is at `12(%ebp)`

Comment: @Jester Ok. Now I have `cache` and `addr` stored in `ecx` and `cl`, respectively. I get that each member of `cache` is a full byte because they are `char`s, but can you elaborate on your third point, please? I don't understand how I would iterate through the struct or access each `block` item. Should I use register `esi/edi` for `cache` so I can loop through its contents?

Comment: You can loop using whatever register you prefer. Note that `cl` is the low 8 bits of `ecx` so you can't use them at the same time.